# How can I convert raw pixel data to AVI video?

Tags: video-processing, video

I have series of gray-scale 8-bit frames and I want to convert them into AVI video. How can I do this? Is there any existing converting utils or products for this type of task? I even do not understand how my format is called, is what I have (digitized stream from analogue interlaced PAL TV-camera) could be considered as RAW video?

Example of what I have in my .bin file:
(do not pay attention to sliced frame, I will fix this with preconversion processing, and I still have to deinterlace this frames)

[image]

Comment: I think that ffmpeg should be able to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to open the file in VLC which supports quite many formats? http://www.videolan.org/

Comment: @MBaz , thank you! your lead was very helpfull!

Comment: @stronk_kisik You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

My format is called Y-only or GRAY video.

I do it this way:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s:v 640x200 -i orbita_data.y -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.avi
```

The really good part is that I even do not need to deinterlace it myself, ffmpeg could do it for me too.

P.S. many thanks MBaz for this lead